# Android ADB backup APK injection vulnerability

Tags: android, security, android-backup-service, backup-agent

I have gone through below links-

https://github.com/irsl/ADB-Backup-APK-Injection/

https://threatpost.com/bug-in-android-adb-backup-system-can-allow-injection-of-malicious-apps/113701/

and found-

> There’s a severe vulnerability in the way that all versions of Android
>   handle the restoration of backups that can allow an attacker to inject
>   a malicious APK file into the backup archive. The bug is the result of
>   an issue with the ADB command-line tool for Android and the
>   researchers who discovered it say there is no fix for it right now.

I have not used [BackupAgent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupAgent.html) class in my project.Is my project still Android Backup Vulnerable which can allow injection of malicious apps?

As per the link

> The attacker first needs to convince the user to install an
>   application with the malicious BackupAgent class.

So can i assume that there is no way an app is vulnerable to this issue if it is not using custom BackupAgent class?